# How do you open a file - not an application - as an administrator?

Tags: windows-8, administrator

I know how to open an application as an administrator - you simple right click and select "Run as Administrator".

I am doing that with my application, PhotoImpact. The problem is, that the "Open" feature in the application is freezing whenever I use it, so I want to open the file I need directly by clicking on it in Explorer. The problem with that is that I need to open the application and thus the file in Administrator mode for it work.

So my question is, how do you open a file and specify that the application it opens with should be opened in Administrator mode?

Comment: Won't add another answer as you have a good answer below, however I will add something to try; you can go to the photoimpact application file (exe) right click then properties and within the compatibility tab you have run as administrator. If you tick this and then simply open your files that are using that program is should default as running as administrator however it only works with certain software.

Comment: @CharlesH your suggestion is better than the answer, but unfortunately didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Explorer as an administrator, then every file you open with it should also be opening as an administrator too?

Of course, watch out for deleting or moving important things when running Explorer as an administrator (root).

If your specific case, you may want to find an update or fix for `PhotoImpact`, since opening a file is a pretty basic and important feature, if it's crashing there it's not instilling confidence in it's stability.